# Remove rows from a data frame found in another df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["Peter", "John", "Jack", "Mark", "Adam", "Mike", "Aaron", "Mike"],
    "age": [25, 34, 58, 29, 42, 39, 48, 24],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["Mark", "Jack", "Adam", "Mike"],
    "age": [29, 58, 42, 39],
    "is_funny": [False, True, True, False],
})
```

I want to remove all rows present in `df2` from `df1` matching in `name` and `age`. This would result in the following data frame:

```py
>>> df3
    name  age
0  Peter   25
1   John   34
2  Aaron   48
3   Mike   24
```

`df.isin()` only seems to work on ordered rows and checks using index (not the case here).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use outer merge:

```
df2.merge(df1, on=['name','age'], how='outer', indicator=True)\
   .query('_merge == "right_only"').reindex(df1.columns, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    name  age
4  Peter   25
5   John   34
6  Aaron   48
7   Mike   24
```

Comment: i was going to close as a dupe with [pandas merge 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) but maybe it's not a total dupe due to reindex

Answer (score 3):

You can use `isin` on both columns, like:

```
df1[~df1.set_index(['name','age']).index.isin(df2.set_index(['name','age']).index)]
```

---

```
Out[177]: 
    name  age
0  Peter   25
1   John   34
6  Aaron   48
7   Mike   24
```

Answer (score 2):

Outer Merge will select the data as you described.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["Peter", "John", "Jack", "Mark", "Adam", "Mike", "Aaron", "Mike"],
    "age": [25, 34, 58, 29, 42, 39, 48, 24],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["Mark", "Jack", "Adam", "Mike"],
    "age": [29, 58, 42, 39],
    "is_funny": [False, True, True, False],
})

df3 = df2.merge(df1, on=['name','age'], how='outer', indicator=True).query('_merge == "right_only"').reindex(df1.columns, axis=1)

print(df3)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
df1[df1.merge(df2, on=['name','age'], how='left', indicator=True)['_merge']=='left_only']

#     name  age
# 0  Peter   25
# 1   John   34
# 6  Aaron   48
# 7   Mike   24
```

Or:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1.assign(source=1),df2.assign(source=2)])
df3 = df3.drop_duplicates(df1.columns, keep=False)
df3 = df3[df3['source'] == 1][df1.columns]

#     name  age
# 0  Peter   25
# 1   John   34
# 6  Aaron   48
# 7   Mike   24
```